# How can I import string from Excel into MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, import

I want to import a row of headers form Excel into matlab then put each header into its according variable's name in MATLAB. Just like the picture below shows, I import all the variables into a matrix 'X', then I would like to import the header one by one to rename all the columns. Is there any way to do this? 
 [image]

Comment: this should get you started: [read complicated excel or csv file into matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7234783/97160)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation of [xlsread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html); you have to load all the data:

from matlab doc: Example

*Request the numeric data, text, and a copy of the unprocessed (raw) data from myExample.xlsx:*

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx')

ndata =
     1     2     3
     4     5   NaN
     7     8     9

text = 
    'First'    'Second'    'Third'
    ''         ''          ''     
    ''         ''          'x'    

alldata = 
    'First'    'Second'    'Third'
    [    1]    [     2]    [    3]
    [    4]    [     5]    'x'    
    [    7]    [     8]    [    9]
```

In case you know in which cells the headers are, you can also specify a range to read from the excel file:

```
[~, headers, ~ ] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx','A1:C1');
```

this gives (for the example data used above ^^):

```
headers = 
    'First'    'Second'    'Third'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import Excel files using the workspace GUI or `help xlsread`.

You can also copy and paste data by first creating an empty cell array with `a = cell(1)` from the command prompt, then double clicking the variable and copy/pasting from Excel into it (use "Paste Excel data").

Comment: I used 'xlsread' to import all the data, but not the headers. Headers cannot be imported by that.